# how to find out number of http request per second coming to glassfish server?

Tags: http, https, glassfish, performance-testing

I have to provide the performance report of my application to my lead.
So I have to find out , how many http request are coming to my glassfish server at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable more detailed logging in glassfish to see all the request in log file:

http://blog.igorminar.com/2009/12/configuring-common-access-log-format-in.html

for monitoring and checking all statistic You can use for example "JavaMelody"

[image]

User guid for JavaMelody

https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide